# How to multiply all the values in an array in PHP

Tags: php

I am having trouble multiplying the values in my array.

When I echo the $buy_option_num; it generates all the array

I need to multiply all the values generated by the $buy_option_num variable.

I have tried both multiply([$buy_option_num]) and array_product ($buy_option_num) but I can't get it to work.

Here the code;

```
<?php
            //calculate
            $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

            $mlist = test_get_user_unsubmitted_list($user_ID);
            
            $buy_option_ids = unserialize($mlist['buy_options_ids']);
            $buy_options_ids = unserialize($mlist['buy_options_ids']);
            
            foreach ($buy_options_ids as $buy_option_ID => $buy_option_num) {
                
                echo $buy_option_num;
                
            }
?>

Thanks.
```

Comment: What do you want to multiply them by?

Comment: @Nick I think he means calculate the product of all of them -- multiply them by each other.

Comment: @Barmar you may be right, it's really unclear...

Comment: The argument to `array_product` should be the array, not the elements. `array_product($buy_options_ids)`

Comment: ```array_product($buy_options_ids)``` Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you supply to `array_product()` should be the array, not the elements.

So, updating your code we get:

```
<?php
        //calculate
        $user_ID = get_current_user_id();

        $mlist = test_get_user_unsubmitted_list($user_ID);
        
        $buy_option_ids = unserialize($mlist['buy_options_ids']);
        $buy_options_ids = unserialize($mlist['buy_options_ids']);

        echo array_product($buy_option_ids);
        
?>
```

<sup>Reference:[array_product()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-product.php)</sup>